# How can I obtain information from a third table in this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

```
TABLE appointment (AppointmentNumber, ApptDate, PatientNumber, DentistID)

TABLE patientstable PatientNumber, PatientForename, PatientSurname, DentistID

TABLE dentists DentistID, DentistForename, DentistSurname
```

I am running this

```
SELECT appointment.AppointmentNumber, appointment.ApptDate, 
patientstable.PatientForename, patientstable.PatientSurname 
FROM patientstable 
INNER JOIN appointment ON (patientstable.PatientNumber=appointment.PatientNumber)
```

Which gives me the dates and patient name details for each appointment.

I want to display the `DentistForenam`e and `DentistSurname` related to each appointment too but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Just add another join like you did with the `appointment` table.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is another join to dentist table like this:

```
SELECT appointment.AppointmentNumber,
       appointment.ApptDate,
       patientstable.PatientForename,
       patientstable.PatientSurname,
       dentist.DentistForename,
       dentist.DentistSurname
FROM patientstable
INNER JOIN appointment 
 ON patientstable.PatientNumber=appointment.PatientNumber
INNER JOIN dentists
 ON(appointment.DentistID = dentist.DentistID)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT appointment.AppointmentNumber, appointment.ApptDate, patientstable.PatientForename, patientstable.PatientSurname
FROM patientstable
INNER JOIN appointment 
 ON patientstable.PatientNumber=appointment.PatientNumber 
inner join dentists 
on patientstable.dentistsid = dentists.dentistsid

Join One more Tbale to get columns from Dentists Table